# AWS Amplify - verify email using verifyUserAttribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have set MFA to verify the phone number on sign up. I am trying to verify the user's email using verifyUserAttribute. I have passed the attribute as 'email'. Still I'm receiving the verification for the mobile number, not the email. Any idea how to fix this?

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
  .then(user => Auth.verifyUserAttribute(user, 'email'))
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Does your user pool require verification of both email and phone number or just the email?

Comment: Currently in AWS, we can only verify one, as per the client requirement, I need to verify the mobile on sig-up and verify the the email later.

Comment: I ask because according to the documentation for Cognito `If a user signs up with both a phone number and an email address, and your user pool settings require verification of both attributes, a verification code is sent via SMS to the phone. The email address is not verified, so your app needs to call GetUser to see if an email address is awaiting verification. If it is, the app should call GetUserAttributeVerificationCode to initiate the email verification flow and then submit the verification code by calling VerifyUserAttribute. `